# How to show a div box when user firstly checked a checkbox out of some checkboxes it may be 7 or more and hide on last uncheck of any checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want to get appear a div box when user checks any first checkbox.

I have also tried following codes:
JQ Codes:

```
$('#checkbox').change(function() {
     if ($(this:first).is(':checked')) {
          console.log('Checked');
     } else {
         console.log('Unchecked');
     }
});
```

HTML Codes:

```
<?php foreach ($band_data as $row) { ?>
     <fieldset>
          <legend>Text</legend>
          <input type="checkbox" class="scheme-check" id="checkscheme" name="checkme">
     </fieldset>
<?php } ?>

<!--Div to be shown on hide-->

<div class=counter-box></div>
```

But not working please tell me any correct method to do so.

First of all thanks for instant help; I should mention the case properly to avoid misunderstanding. I use those new codes but due to 'toggle' event its hiding when I checked/unchecked any checkbox. I want to show box till last checkbox is checked and will be hide it on last uncheck.

Comment: Can you share your HTML with us?

Comment: I am using it with php foreach function in codeignater: giving base format of that code:

Comment: You can access your HTML via View Source on your browser. Without HTML your question cannot be answered.

Comment: Giving same `id` for all the checkboxes isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

(HTML)

```
<input class="check-box" type="checkbox">Check Me</input>
  <input class="check-box" type="checkbox">Check Me</input>
  <input class="check-box" type="checkbox">Check Me</input>
  <input class="check-box" type="checkbox">Check Me</input>

  <div class="hidden"></div>
```

(CSS)

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

(JavaScript)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  checkBox();
});
function checkBox() {
    $('.check-box').on("change", function() {
      $('.hidden').toggle();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks friends I got what I want #TimeRewinder, you caught exact that. Thanks again and again.

Comment: I got one thing here that Java Script codes are working for only first check box checked but I want same effect on all check box by which visitor checks any of checkbox first time the box will show else hide. Please tell me it.

Comment: I misunderstood your initial question. Anyway I just edited the answer removed ':first-of-type' from the selector. Should do what you need..

Comment: First of all thanks for instant help; I should mention the case properly to avoid misunderstanding. I use those new codes but due to 'toggle' event its hiding when I checked/unchecked any checkbox. I want to show box till last checkbox is checked and will be hide it on last uncheck. Please, help me to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are doing is correct but use class instead of id

```
$('.scheme-check').change(function() {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
console.log('Checked');
} else {
console.log('Unchecked');
}
});
```

Comment: I tried this also but net beans showing error for this ":" first and saying to use "," instead of ":" so those codes not working even after using it as per your suggestion. Is any other way? I am going to describe it properly please have look over it and suggest if any.

Comment: @Masrer Prons I edited the answer. Try this and let me know

Comment: When I checked first checkbox box get appear and on another and another checkbox getting checked, its show but its hide on uncheck of any one checkbox even after some of other checkboxes are still checked. #Tej, I want it to be hide only when all checkboxes get unchecked. Please do something and reply me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/nq65qnr0/

**JavaScript:**

```
// Bind the change event to the common class of all the checkboxes.
$('.scheme-check').change(function(){

  if($(".scheme-check:checked").length>1)   return; // If not the first one, then do nothing.
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      console.log('Checked');
      //show hide div here 
   } 
  else {
   console.log('Unchecked');
  }
});
```

**Assuming your HTML generated to be like this**:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="scheme-check" id="checkscheme1" name="checkme">
<input type="checkbox" class="scheme-check" id="checkscheme2" name="checkme">
<input type="checkbox" class="scheme-check" id="checkscheme3" name="checkme">
.....
```